# How to hide ActionBar, but keep the Tab navigation buttons?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm new in creating `Android` apps, and I would like to hide the `Title, App Icon`, and the whole top area of the `ActionBar`, but keep the Tabs Navigations below it. Is it possible?

Here is an explanation picture about what I want exactly:

[image]

Comment: Not exactly the answer, not sure if what you want can be done easily.
If you use this library for the tabs (https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip)
Then they appear like AB tabs, but are decoupled from the AB.
Bonus, you get Google Play style sliding tab selectors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will show only tabs:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
// Set your tabs below
```